# How to use a value from first method in second method (in the same class)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I want to use the `d` value from `can_add` method for `add` method, but get error `'MoneyBox' object has no attribute 'd'`. How to use `d` value for `add` method?

```
class MoneyBox:
    def __init__(self, capacity = 0):
        self.capacity = capacity

    def can_add(self, v):
        self.v = v
        if self.capacity > self.v:
            self.d = True
            return d
        else:
            self.d = False
            return self.d
        
    def add(self, v):
        self.can_add(v)
        if self.d == True:
            self.v += v
        f = self.capacity - self.v
        return f

a = MoneyBox(10)
a.add(5)
```

Comment: You're mixing local variables (`d`, `v`) with "class variables" (`self.d`, `self.v`).

Comment: `d` isn't defined *anywhere*.

Answer (score 1):

d isn't a variable of the class but only in `can_add` method hence you can't access it in `add` method.
more so, you don't need it anyway, just return true/false.

```
class MoneyBox:
    def __init__(self, capacity = 0):
        self.capacity = capacity

    def can_add(self, v):
        if self.capacity > v:
            return True
        else:
            return False
        
    def add(self, v):
        if self.can_add(v) == True:
            v += v
        f = self.capacity - v
        return f

a = MoneyBox(10)
a.add(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to return a class variable when you want to return a local variable.

```
class MoneyBox:
    def __init__(self, capacity = 0):
        self.capacity = capacity

    def can_add(self, v):
        self.v = v
        if self.capacity > self.v:
            d = True
            return d
        else:
            d = False
            return d
        
    def add(self, v):
        d = self.can_add(v)
        if d == True:
            self.v += v
        f = self.capacity - self.v
        return f

a = MoneyBox(10)
a.add(5)
```

If you want the value to be saved in a class variable you can do it like this

```
class MoneyBox:
    def __init__(self, capacity = 0):
        self.capacity = capacity
        self.d = False

    def can_add(self, v):
        self.v = v
        if self.capacity > self.v:
            self.d = True
            
        else:
            self.d = False
            
        
    def add(self, v):
        self.can_add(v)
        if self.d == True:
            self.v += v
        f = self.capacity - self.v
        return f

a = MoneyBox(10)
a.add(5)
```